# cmd error keeps popping up

Tags: cmd.exe, basic

i keep getting this error msg every like 30 seconds 
its either related to a visual basic compiler which i have no i dea what that is (cuz i dont remember downloading a visual basic programming app )
or its related to .netframework 
i just wanna stop this error from popping up plz help

[image]

Comment: It’s probably malware. There is no `lsm.exe` in Windows.

Comment: thx for the relpy ,,,i scanned for viruses using malwarebytes ,,i managed to clean up some malware but the issue wasnt solved

Comment: @DanielB Yes there is. Local Session Manager (lms.exe).

Comment: @HashemHanqtah Can you access regedit? WIN+R, type 'regedit', and navigate to "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run". Is there any lms.exe entry there?

Comment: @swaglord mcmuffin' i just checked ..no it doesnt 
it had some adobe , windows defender , and reltek audio stuff

Comment: @swaglordmcmuffin' Local Session Manager _Core Windows Service that manages local user sessions. Stopping or disabling this service will result in system instability._  Path to executable `C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch -p`. No ˙lsm.exe˙!

Comment: thx for the help guys ,,,i solved it by actally going to the path written in the title bar of cmd ... in program data the next folder was hidden as a system file ,,it wa malware tho ,,after unhiding it i found the lsm.exe inside and dlted the whole folder ,,,fixed ,,,thx all